# Connecting Stripe with SnipCart

Tags: stripe-payments, snipcart

I would like to use Stripe as a payment gateway with SnipCart, though I can't seem to find a definitive guide to this in either party's documentation. If someone could at least point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done easily by going Account > Payment Gateways in Snipcart's dashboard. Make sure you are in Live mode, then click on Connect under Stripe, you will be able to either link your existing Stripe account or create a new one.